# Network adapter in Hyper-V keeps being reset to DockerNAT

Tags: networking, windows-10, hyper-v, docker, docker-for-windows

I've installed Docker for Windows on my Windows 10 machine, which uses Hyper-V. Its default network adapter (virtual switch) is DockerNAT, an internal network.

If I shut down the VM (the default MobyLinuxVM) and change the network adapter to one using the external network, after restarting the VM, it has switched back to DockerNAT. If I change DockerNAT itself to use the external network, it gets changed back to internal.

Why is that? And what *is* the preferred way of getting some connectivity for Docker?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft describes [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/setup-nat-network) how to add NAT to the DockerNAT switch in order to allow external access.

It boils down to:

```
New-NetNat -Name DockerNAT -InternalIPInterfaceAddressPrefix 10.0.0.0/17
```

Using the IP range configured in Docker 4 Windows.