# Docker for Windows unable to pull images — no connection?

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v, docker, docker-for-windows

I've installed Docker for Windows on my Windows 10 machine, which uses Hyper-V.

Upon opening up a window (either Powershell or regular old command will do) and typing `docker run hello-world`, I get the following response.

```
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers).
See 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe run --help'.
```

Or, most recently:

```
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 192.168.65.1:53: read udp 192.168.65.2:44376->192.168.65.1:53: i/o timeout.
See 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe run --help'.
```

As stated in my related questions, Docker for Windows comes with its own [apparently unalterable](https://superuser.com/q/1188558/278826) network adapter, `DockerNAT`. I suppose I need to have that connect to the outside world, but I'm at a loss how to do so.

I've found advice to change to a fixed DNS, which I've already done (`8.8.8.8`, to be precise). There are no proxies to set.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, all the workarounds mentioned don't seem to work for me. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @IngóVals after uninstalling and reinstalling, suddenly it worked. No clue why. May very well be something network or possibly security related, as I'm on a corporate network.

Answer (score 8):

had the similar issue.

Solution: Right Klick Docker Icon and go to Docker Settings then Network Tab Change DNS from Automatic to Fixed and Check your Proxy Settings.

Comment: Saved my sanity! Thanks. Any idea why this needs to be done? I've now grown weary of docker updates as every update causes things to break and requires tweaks such as these to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

The current version of docker community edition (3.1.0) has a different interface. This answer is for Windows 10 Pro 20H2.

1. After opening the docker interface from the tray application.
2. Go to the "settings" cog icon. Third one from the top right.
3. Open up the "Resources" to show the Proxies/Network/WSL integration
4. Click on the "Network" on the left-hand-side and
5. Lastly click to enable Manual DNS configuration.

*DNS value needs to be specified*

Restart if necessary.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

faced a similar issue, this is because there can be a firewall between your network, if you connect it to direct internet(In my case I connected from my personal hotspot) it will work.